# Security Headers for a single request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement in security headers for laravel project and so far I have figured this out.

https://github.com/to1/security-headers

As mentioned here I added the `Headers.php` file into `/app/http/middleware` and added the code as below in `app/http/kernel.php`.

```
protected $middleware = [
            \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Headers::class // This is our middleware to add/remove headers
    ];
```

But this will will add these headers on each request in the project, But I need to add for **only one specific request only**.Is there a way to achieve this functionality?